# invalid conversion from 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c, embedded

I am writing code in C for STM32 with gcc compiler, I am tried suggestions.
I am calling fuction from i2c.c via i2c.h definiton. May be I did mistake there.
Thanks for comments.

(i2c.h)

```
#define Chip_TxBurst(wREG, wCNT, pbDATA)   \
    I2C_TxBurst((0xC0) | (((wREG) >> 7) & 0x1E), (wREG), (wCNT), (pbDATA))
```

(i2c.c)

```
void I2C_TxBurst (
uint16_t  bSLA,          /* I2C slave address */
uint16_t  bREG,          /* I2C sub-address */
uint16_t  bCNT,          /* The number of data which will be transmitted */
uint8_t  *pbDATA        /* Point to the first DATA item */
)
{
    uint8_t bIdx;

    for (bIdx = 0; bIdx < bCNT; bIdx++)
    {
        I2C_TxData(pbDATA[bIdx]);
    } /* for */

    } /* I2C_TxBurst */
```

(osd.c)

```
void OSD0_TEXT( uint8_t     *TEXT,
                    uint8_t     FONT_SIZE_X,
                    ......
                    )
{
    Chip_TxBurst(0x400, FONT_SIZE_X, TEXT);
}
```

(main)

```
main{
OSD0_TEXT("STAY FOLISH",11);
}
```

#

#

(old question code)

```
void OSD0_TEXT (    uint8_t     *TEXT)
{
.....
TxBurst(0x400, strlen(TEXT), TEXT);
.....
}
main{
OSD0_TEXT("STAY FOLISH");
}
```

Comment: You pass `char[N]` to a function(`OS0_TEXT`) that expects `uint8_t` and you pass `uint8_t` to a function(`strlen`) that expects `const char*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking, `uint8_t` and `char` may not always be compatible, since `char` has implementation-defined signedness and could be a signed type on some compilers.

In practice, casting to/from `uint8_t` to/from `char` will always work when `char` is used for storing ASCII characters, since there are no symbol tables with negative indices.

Side-notes:

- You should always strive for const correctness, *especially* when creating pointers to string literals.
- The size of string literals could be computed at compile-time, to save a little bit of time.
- main() returns void on any bare metal ARM system I have ever seen. It does not return int, because that wouldn't make any sense (return to who?).

So the proper fix for your code is:

```
void OSD0_TEXT (const uint8_t* TEXT, size_t size)
{
  ...
  TxBurst(0x400, size, TEXT);
  ...
}

void main (void)
{
  static const char STR[] = "STAY FOOLISH"; // static to ensure it wont end up in RAM
  const size_t STR_LEN = sizeof(STR) - 1;

  OSD0_TEXT((const uint8_t*)STR, STR_LEN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void OSD0_TEXT (    const char *TEXT)
{
.....
TxBurst(0x400, strlen(TEXT), TEXT);
.....
}
main{
OSD0_TEXT("STAY FOLISH");
}
```